# ansible lookup plugin does not work on AWX

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-awx

I tried lookup on machine installed on it ansible and it works, but when uploading playbook to awx it does not work.

```
  - name: get file
    set_fact:
      policer: "{{ lookup('file', 'file.txt') }}"
```

it gives An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'file'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: could not locate file in lookup"

although the file in the same repo of playbook, and have worked on machine but not awx. And if there is something specific to remote hosts how to know the path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible [Lookup plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#lookup-plugins) "*execute and are evaluated on the Ansible **control machine**.*"

1. The play works fine when you run it at the localhost (control machine) where the file is located

```bash
shell> hostname
test_11
shell> cat /tmp/file.txt 
content of file /tmp/file.txt
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb1.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    policer: "{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/file.txt') }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: policer
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb1.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  policer: content of file /tmp/file.txt

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

2. When you move to another controller (might be AWX) the file remains at the remote host (*test_11* in the example) and is not available at the localhost controller. You can test it. See the block below

```bash
shell> hostname
awx
shell> cat /tmp/file.txt
cat: /tmp/file.txt: No such file or directory
shell> ssh admin@test_11 cat /tmp/file.txt
content of file /tmp/file.txt
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb2.yml
- hosts: test_11
  vars:
    policer: "{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/file.txt') }}"
  tasks:
    - block:
        - stat:
            path: /tmp/file.txt
          register: st
        - debug:
            var: st.stat.exists
      delegate_to: localhost
    - debug:
        var: policer
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb2.yml

PLAY [test_11] *******************************************************************************

TASK [stat] **********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11 -> localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11 -> localhost] => 
  st.stat.exists: false

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
[WARNING]: Unable to find '/tmp/file.txt' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to see paths)
```

> fatal: [test_11]: FAILED! =>
> msg: 'An unhandled exception occurred while templating ''{{ lookup(''file'', ''/tmp/file.txt'') }}''. Error was a <class ''ansible.errors.AnsibleError''>, original message: An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin ''file''. Error was a <class ''ansible.errors.AnsibleError''>, original message: could not locate file in lookup: /tmp/file.txt. could not locate file in lookup: /tmp/file.txt'

```yaml
PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_11: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

There are many options for how to fix it. The trivial one is moving also the file to the localhost controller. If the file remains at the remote host you can either read it by *command* or *slurp*, or *fetch* it. The module *command* always reports *changed*. The modules *slurp* and *fetch* are idempotent.

3. Read the file by *command*

```yaml
shell> cat pb3.yml
- hosts: test_11
  vars:
    policer: "{{ out.stdout }}"
  tasks:
    - command: cat /tmp/file.txt
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: policer
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb3.yml

PLAY [test_11] *******************************************************************************

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
changed: [test_11]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  policer: content of file /tmp/file.txt

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_11: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

4. Read the file by *slurp*. This should be used for smaller files only because (quoting from *slurp*): "*This module returns an ‘in memory’ base64 encoded version of the file, take into account that this will require at least twice the RAM as the original file size.*"

```yaml
shell> cat pb4.yml
- hosts: test_11
  vars:
    policer: "{{ out.content|b64decode }}"
  tasks:
    - slurp:
        path: /tmp/file.txt
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: policer
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb4.yml

PLAY [test_11] *******************************************************************************

TASK [slurp] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  policer: |-
    content of file /tmp/file.txt

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_11: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

5. The next option is to *fetch* the file to the local directory *dest* (will be created). By default, the file(s) is stored in the directory named by the remote host

```yaml
shell> cat pb5.yml
- hosts: test_11
  vars:
    file_path: "/tmp/fetched_files/{{ inventory_hostname }}/tmp/file.txt"
    policer: "{{ lookup('file', file_path)  }}"
  tasks:
    - fetch:
        src: /tmp/file.txt
        dest: /tmp/fetched_files
    - debug:
        var: policer
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb5.yml

PLAY [test_11] *******************************************************************************

TASK [fetch] *********************************************************************************
changed: [test_11]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  policer: content of file /tmp/file.txt

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_11: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/fetched_files/test_11/tmp/file.txt 
content of file /tmp/file.txt
```

**Notes**

- An absolute path to the file is used in the examples. See [The magic of ‘local’ paths](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbook_pathing.html#the-magic-of-local-paths) on how to use relative paths locally.